# Append click event to appended Iframe elements

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get this to work. I hav appeneded an element in an iframe  and need to run a click event on it.

I've tried these and non seem to work anyway ideas?

```
$(document).on('click',iframe.contents().find('[data-mailbuilder="article-repeat"] .plus'),function() {});
```

and

```
iframe.contents().find('body').on('click','[data-mailbuilder="article-repeat"] .plus',function() {});
```

Comment: where's the code that adds the element? Can bind directly to new element when you create it

Comment: `iframe.contents().find('[data-mailbuilder="article-repeat"]').append('<span class="minus"></span><span class="plus">+</span>');` That's the code that adds the element.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
$(iframe[0].contentWindow.document).on('click' ...
```

seems to get it.